# How to get max_amount, min_amount from Contribution Page

Tags: civicontribute, api

Issue: Coding wordpress plugin for civicontribute widget, I need to get some variables in order to build the progress bar.

When I use `civicrm_api3('contribution_page', 'getfields');` it returns a lot of information which does not seem to be accessible when using `civicrm_api3('contribution_page', 'get', $params);`.

May some of you put a bot of light on how to get this data?

PS. May it be easier to code an alternative template for the widget?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

what is that you have in the param?

I would suggest you to use the api explorer, it should guide you and the generated code can be copy/pasted in your plugin

Just to be clear: the min_amount and max_amount are the amounts a user CAN enter, it doesn't show how much has been given already. for that, you should look at the contribution api.getcount (and filter it by contribution_page)